# How to make a replace on each line of file by finding a string

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to replace a string with an other one on each line in a file by a string match in powershell.

example I have this file;

```
dmadmin;Trusted Client;F;
d2_mail_manager;Ticket;F;
dmadmin;Trusted Client;F;
d2_mail_manager;Ticket;F;
d2_mail_manager;Ticket;F;
```

I would Like to find the string dmadmin and Replace ";F;" by ";T;" on each line like that

```
dmadmin;Trusted Client;T;
d2_mail_manager;Ticket;F;
dmadmin;Trusted Client;T;
d2_mail_manager;Ticket;F;
d2_mail_manager;Ticket;F;
```

what is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [answer from Pawel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51768987/52598) is the preferred way imo but following is an alternative using regular expressions. <sub>There's usually more than one way to skin a cat</sub>

```
@'
dmadmin;Trusted Client;F;
d2_mail_manager;Ticket;F;
dmadmin;Trusted Client;F;
d2_mail_manager;Ticket;F;
d2_mail_manager;Ticket;F;
'@ | % {
    $_ -replace "(dmadmin.*)F;", '$1T;'
}
```

Comment: many thanks both of you, The solution from Pawel is working fine with string without space, but doesn't work with string with space. The solution from Lieven is working for the two cases.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like CSV-like file to me. If that's true, you can use following script:

```
#demo data
@'
dmadmin;Trusted Client;F;
d2_mail_manager;Ticket;F;
dmadmin;Trusted Client;F;
d2_mail_manager;Ticket;F;
d2_mail_manager;Ticket;F;
'@ | out-file C:\Temp\test.csv

import-csv c:\temp\test.csv -Delimiter ';' -Header 'Role','Type','Flag' | % {
    if ($_.Role -eq 'dmadmin') { $_.Flag='T' }
    "$($_.Role);$($_.Type);$($_.Flag);"
} | Out-File C:\Temp\test2.csv
```

Comment: You can skip the writing and reading to a file by using `ConvertFrom-Csv`. Other than that, this should be the preferred option.